# Trying to Extract Football Data

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the information from each match of the following form. I can access this tbody but then do not know how to proceed.

```
<tbody class="matchCentreStatsContainer"><tr><td><p class="higher">64.6</p></td><td><p>Possession %</p></td><td><p class="">35.4
</p></td></tr><tr><td><p class="higher">7</p>
</td><td><p>Shots on target</p></td>
<td><p class="">1</p></td></tr><tr><td><p class="higher">15</p></td><td><p>Shots</p>
</td><td><p class="">4</p></td></tr><tr><td><p class="higher">757</p></td>
<td><p>Touches</p></td><td><p class="">510</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="higher">543</p></td><td><p>Passes</p></td><td><p class="">301</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="higher">24</p></td><td><p>Tackles</p></td><td><p class="">23</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="">12</p></td><td><p>Clearances</p></td><td><p class="higher">22</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="higher">9</p></td><td><p>Corners</p></td><td><p class="">0</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="">3</p></td><td><p>Offsides</p></td><td><p class="higher">2</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="">2</p></td><td><p>Yellow cards</p></td><td><p class="higher">1</p></td></tr>
<tr><td><p class="">15</p></td><td><p>Fouls conceded</p></td><td><p class="higher">12</p></td></tr></tbody>
```

I have the following code to access it and cannot move from there. Any help to extract the data such as passes, touches, possession, and the like would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.premierleague.com/match/46889"
page = requests.get(url)
import bs4
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
tablediv = soup.find(name='div', attrs={'data-ui-tab':'Match Stats'})
tablediv.tbody
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site uses a Rest API to get the data from the client side. You need to call :

```
GET https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/stats/match/{matchID}
```

The result is JSON data, you can get the stats by looking at the `data` field, stats object are indexed by the id of both teams :

```
import requests
import json

matchID = "46889"
match = requests.get(
    f"https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/stats/match/{matchID}",
    headers = {
        "origin": "https://www.premierleague.com"
    }
)
data = json.loads(match.text)

teams = [(t["team"]["id"], t["team"]["name"]) for t in data["entity"]["teams"]]

print(teams)

for t in teams:
    print(f"stats for team {t[1]} with id {t[0]}")
    stats = data["data"][str(t[0])]
    print(stats)
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! Hope you are staying safe!

Comment: @pineapple69 thank you, you’re welcome; you can accept the answer if it’s good for you

Comment: Could you just explain where that API comes from?

Comment: Use chrome console with the network tab and go to the stats tab. It will show up